# What is the Python syntax of Ti.API.fireEvent?

Tags: python, titanium, tidesdk

To be specific, I need the Python equivalent of this:

```
Ti.API.fireEvent('custom_event', { row_id : 10; });
```

I tried this:

```
Ti.API.fireEvent('custom_event', { 'row_id' : 10 })
```

But, I'm not able to retrieve the parameter values on the listener side. It's got to be something with the dict-KObject conversion, that I'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

i think you could do it like this:

```
// listen:
Ti.API.addEventListener("sEventName",function(e){
    var sValue = Ti.API.get("keyName");
    Ti.API.info(sValue);
});

// fire:
Ti.API.set("keyName","value goes here");
Ti.API.fireEvent("sEventName");
```

Answer (score 0):

that should be  Ti.App.fireEvent () not   Ti.API.fireEvent()

Comment: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.API-method-fireEvent

Hasn't it been moved or something? Because, Ti.API.fireEvent() is working perfectly fine. Just that I'm not able to pass parameters properly.